# Out of the box sync service for mobile app

Tags: java, android, amazon-redshift, amazon-cognito

amazon-cognito
I have a mobile app that collects a lot of medical data from the user and every ~30 minutes needs to send the new data to the server.

I need 2 things:

1- Sync between the server and the app the data. If a user login from another mobile device he should get all of his past data and have full picture of his history.

2- the data that is being sync with the server should be store also on data base that I can query for analytics purposes.

What do you suppose to be the architecture ? What technologies do you recomend for that? I thought to use aws Cognito with Redshift but it is limited to 20 MB for each user.

My main question is there any out of the box sync service that i can copy it also for my BI DB like Redshift?

Comment: Redshift is for 'big data'. i am guessing your data might not be so large, so Redshift might not be a good fit for you.

Comment: mt data is going to be large, going to svae there teras of data and need to do BI on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the AWS Mobile Hub site.  It will produce a sample app with the functionality you are talking about.  You then click to download that sample app.

It will produce an IOS app in Objective-c or Swift, or an Android app (in java?).

It will sync up to 1M per user using Cognito Sync, but the app can also provide access to files through S3 or database through DynamoDB.

Comment: But If my user data will increase? For example a spefic user will have 50 mb of history  data.

Comment: Well I cannot speak to the costs involved, but AWS can store SQL, NoSql databases, Files, and Streams.  Cognito Sync is just one approach which might make sense for you. You can always keep more than the limit by using one of the other databases.Limits in Cognito Sync
Max number of datasets per identity 20
Max number of records per dataset 1024
Max size of a single dataset 1 MB

Comment: for example if I have user with 50 MB of data but AWS Cognito is limit to 20 MB what can I do? and this user moved to other device I  need to download all the 50 MB.

Comment: For your purposes, i think Cognito is a system for maintaining identity of an authenticated user on a device. Cognito also has user state data that can "sync" to the device.  But that is just a "nice extra".  Cognito also has a credentialsProvider which issues credentials to authenticated users and allows you to use ALL of the various AWS capabilities you choose.  Those capabilities do not have any meaningful limits.  So you could authenticate users, sync some data or not, but then associate the user with an arbitrarily large database or file on AWS.